# I want to delete a product in database but using .remove() is returning an error that product.remove is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, backend

This is my code:

```
const deleteProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)

  if (product) {
    await product.remove()
    res.json({ message: 'Product removed' })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Product not found')
  }
```

I also have the same problem with deleting a user:

```
const deleteUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

  if (user) {
    await user.remove();
    res.json({ message: 'User removed' });
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }
});
```

How should I fix it? I am building this from a tutorial but the guy is using mongoose v5.10.2 and I am using version v7.

This is my [productModle](https://github.com/niruparekh09/shopee-website/blob/main/backend/models/productModel.js)

Comment: I don't see a problem, but you might consider using `findByIdAndRemove` instead.

Comment: The mongoose 7 documentation seems to be inconsistent.  The example for [$isDeleted](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.$isDeleted()) shows using `Document.remove()`, but the [Document API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html) doesn't list a 'remove' function.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I found a solution using deleteOne().

Here's your updated code:

```
const deleteProduct = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)

  if (product) {
    await product.deleteOne()
    res.json({ message: 'Product removed' })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Product not found')
  }
```

This question was asked 9 months ago and you may have found a solution but this answer may help someone in future.